# Pytest <> Apache airflow ImportError

Tags: python, pytest, airflow, python-import, importerror

The project structure for airflow looks like this (with **init**.py in each folder):

```
/dags
    /dagA.py
    /dagB.py
    /utils
        /custom_operator.py
        ...
/tests
    /test1.py
    ...
```

The imports within dags look like this:
`from utils.A.B import C`

Which works fine for airflow, but when running pytest:
`python3 -m pytest tests/*`

I get import/ModuleNotFound errors within the dags. But when I switch to these imports:
`from dags.utils.A.B import C`
the pytests run without any errors but I get similar errors in the airflow environment.

How can I run pytest differently so that these import issues do not occur (without changing actual airflow code in the dags)?

I tried relative imports, but that has it's own set of errors when importing from parent directories, and no solution online worked completely (other than some saying to use absolute imports, which brought me back to square one).

Answer (score 1):

Move your tests to 'dags' and exclude the tests folder from scanning with .airflowignore

Comment: This is great, thank you - didn’t know this was a thing!